# Update one postgrsql table with sum from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to update hours column in employee table with sum from logtable (time intervals) and could not quite get there. here's what tried.

```
 UPDATE emptable e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT employee, SUM(time_interval) as total
    FROM logtable 
    GROUP BY employee 
) l
ON e.id = l.employee
SET e.hours = l.total
```

Here is the ERROR:

```
syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 2: INNER JOIN (
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 27
```

I tried few variants of this but I strongly this one should have worked and I don't know why it has not, any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What is `time interval`?  I assume your question is about the syntax of the `update`, but that also looks like an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in Postgres is:

```
    UPDATE payroll_employee e
    SET hours = l.total
FROM (SELECT employee, SUM(end_date - start_date) AS total
    FROM payroll_timelog
    GROUP BY employee) l
WHERE e.id = l.employee
```

Comment: should have been time_interval I just edited it. Also I just ran your code, I get ERROR:  column "e" of relation "payroll_emptable" does not exist
LINE 2:  SET e.hours = l.total
             ^

Comment: Gordon Linoff, how do I add a date filter in payroll_timelog so that the SUM is greater 2020-09-01?

Comment: @KuyatehYankz . . . Just add a `where` clause in the subquery.